# Update event in Kendo Grid is not firing

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read:
                {
                    url: "http://dnndev.me:80/DesktopModules/ServicePoint/api/DropData/Drop",
                    dataType: "json",
                },
            destroy:
                {
                    url: "http://dnndev.me/DesktopModules/ServicePoint/api/DeleteCategory/DeleteCategorybyid",
                    type: "DELETE"
                },
            update:
                {
                    url: "http://dnndev.me:80/DesktopModules/ServicePoint/api/updateCategory/update",
                    type: "POST",
           },

                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                     return {
                       models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                             };
                         }
                        }
                },


        },
        schema:
            {
                model:
                    {
                        id: "CategoryID",

                        fields: {
                            CategoryID: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "number" },
                            CategoryName: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },

                        }

                    }
            }
    });

    $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:dataSource,
        editable: "inline",
        columns: [
          {
              field: "CategoryID",
              title: "number",

          },
        {
            field: "CategoryName",
            title: "Name"

        },

    {
        command: ["edit",
        {
            name: "destroy",
            text: "remove",

        }

        ],
       }
        ],

        height: "500px",
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
    }).data("kendoGrid");

});
```

The read and destroy operation are working fine but while doing the update  it's  not even firing the URL(cross checked with Inspect element),as well as I checked my service in POSTMAN it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove , from

```
type: "POST",
```

should be

```
update:{
                url: "http://dnndev.me:80/DesktopModules/ServicePoint/api/updateCategory/update",
                type: "POST"
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it not a right solution any how after updating the Jquery to version 1.9  it is working.